# windows.create does not work properly in Opera for type "popup"

Tags: opera-extension

I'm currently trying to port my Chrome extension [Prime Player](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/prime-player-for-google-p/npngaakpdgeaajbnidkkginekmnaejbi) to Opera. It has a miniplayer that is opened as a separate window (using [windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create)) of type "popup", "panel" or "detached_panel" (depending on a user setting). The latter ones seem to not be supported at all (which is acceptable since they are experimental in Chrome) and type "popup" displays the address bar (which is completely useless and ugly here). See the Opera version left, the Chrome version right:

[image: Screenshot of popup in Opera][image: Screenshot of popup in Chrome]

My question is: Is that a bug or is there some option to hide the address bar?

The [spec](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/apis.html) just says that [chrome.windows](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) does not differ from the Chrome implementation. So, I would expect this to work the same way which means:

1. no address bar
2. "panel" / "detached_panel" fall back to "popup" if "--enable-panels" flag is not set
3. option under opera://flags to enable panels

I also tried to open a window of type "popup" with a mod of the [sample window extension](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/samples/WinTabs-PrivateWindow.nex) which did not work either.
Maybe the difference just has to be clarified in the docs.

Other issues are that the window icon (added by a `<link rel="shortcut icon">`) is not respected in Opera and that the popup has a forced minimum height which leads to empty space at the bottom.